# Dropping every row with len >2 Pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, drop

Suppose I have a dataframe

```
. Values
0  25
1  897
2  48 
3  28
4  214
5  25
```

I am trying to drop all rows with len > 2 with the following code but nothing happens when I run it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('File.csv')

for index in df.index:
    if len(df.loc[index, 'Sevens']) > 2:
        df.drop([index])
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['Value'].str.len() <=2]
```

If values was numbers:

```
df1 = df[df['Value'].astype(str).str.len() <=2]
```